# Formatting Dynamic Edittext Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

ANDROID
I have a layout defined in xml and have a static textview, edittext and checkboxes which are all formatted as below:

```
android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textSize="14dp"
android:width="180dp"
```

I add `textview`, `edittext` and `checkbox` dynamically. I need the new added ones to have the same visual display as the ones already present(static ones) on the layout! Could someone guide or point me how to go about it?

Comment: Please see my answer and if it is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the layout  by inflating each time you need textview, edittext and chekbox.This way your layout will have same look.Because you are reusing your static layout in xml.

See [Layout Inflating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) for details

You have a layout with textview,edittext and checkbox.Now you will use the layout as a view.Like you said for each row you have to inflate the layout and add it to the row.So for every row you will have the copy of the layout.

```
TableLayout layout=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tblLayout);
```

Now you can add the view after inflating the layout

```
   View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null, true);
   TableRow tblrow=new TableRow(this);
   tblRow.add(rowView);
   layout.add(tblRow);
```

Comment: i am using a LinearLayout for each row of the screen and then for the dynamic part i have added a tablelayout!could you please give me some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You can **create any control Dynamic** like this way.

Here i show for Edit Text same way you can do for others.

```
 EditText et = new EditText(this);  
 et.setText("");
 et.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: that i have already tried, but the dynamic ones look bigger than the existing ones

Comment: you can set here height and width problematically  .

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for dynamic configurations about EditText.

```
EditText my_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.weight = 2.0f;
my_edit.setLayoutParams(params);
my_edit.setTextSize(20);
my_edit.setWidth(180);
my_edit.setSingleLine(true);
```

For this you must need LinearLayout as a parent of your EditText.

I hope this helps you somehow.

Thanks.