# Dynamicaly create checkboxes in Android App

Tags: android, checkbox

I have to create checkboxes in my app dynamicaly.The number of checkboxes depends on the response from the server.I can create the checkboxes dynamically as per the response from the server using list view.But the requirement is that the checkboxes should be loaded in two columns. Please check the image attached.Please help me.Thanks in advance[image: Required Gui]

Comment: I think you should create a table layout dynamically with 2 columns and as many rows are required by you (according to server response) and add checkboxes to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically create a TableLayout and fill it up with Checkboxes.

Something like that:

```
            TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(getActivity());
            int offset_in_column=0, table_size=/*the size of your answer from the server*/;
            TableRow tr=null;
            for (int offset_in_table=0; offset_in_table < table_size; offset_in_table++) {
                /* maybe you want to do something special with the data from the server here ? */

                if (offset_in_column == 0) {
                    tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
                    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                }
                CheckBox check = new CheckBox(getActivity());
                check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        /* add your code here */
                    }
                });
                check.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
                tr.addView(check);

                offset_in_column++;
                if (offset_in_column == 2) {

                    tl.addView(tr);
                    offset_in_column = 0;
                }
            }
            if (offset_in_column != 0)
               tl.addView(tr);
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement onclicklistener for the dynamically created check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Table Layout and add Check Box Dynamically in that.

Show my [**`this answer`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250231/formatting-dynamic-edittext-android/13250356#13250356) you can do by this way.

You must edit this code as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this post will be useful

[How to horizontally  align some programmatically added views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796075/how-to-horizontally-align-some-programmatically-added-views)

let me know, if u face any issue